# Collecting the “Multi-person ticket” in the Taiwan Railways Booking app

Tags: trains, tickets, public-transport, transportation, taiwan

I installed the official app, booked two tickets for a train ride, paid, and chose to pickup locally. Now I have one ticket in my app, but the second ticket shows “tickets divided, waiting for pickup”.  The second ticket also has a little green logo of the line app. 
I don’t have the line app, is this necessary to share the ticket?
How does person 2 get her ticket? From what I understand she needs to install the app too but what then? What steps does she need to take to get her ticket into her app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Person 2 has to install the railway app and select “Download ticket” and enter the booking code. No need to install the Line app.